# Change size of text in 'About' page of Big Cartel

Tags: bigcartel

I would like to change the size of the text in my 'About' page of my big cartel shop (foundry theme). I would also like to change it from left-aligned to centralised layout. Where do I find these in the CSS?

Answer (score 0):

To make this change it'd be best to add code to the very bottom of the CSS section in your admin, like so:

```
section.content .custom_page { 
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Simply adjust the `font-size` value to whatever you'd like (the theme default is 14px) and you'll be good to go.